# Select DISTINCT values form @ElementCollection List<String> in @NamedQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss7.x, jpa-2.0, jpql

For a project I'm trying to lookup all distinct categories within a List @ElementCollection field. Each foo instance has one or more String categories assigned. The code below does not work as JBOSS/Hibernate throws an exception when deploying the ear to the server:

```
Error in named query: Foo.listUniqueCategories: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity [SELECT DISTINCT f.categories FROM com.Foo f]
```

I have the class:

```
@Entity(name = "Foo")
@NamedQuery(name = "Foo.listUniqueCategories", query = "SELECT DISTINCT f.categories FROM Foo f")
public class FooEntity
{
   @Id()
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   protected Long id;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name = "categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id"))
   private List<String> categories;

   ...
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the select distinct? Is it even supported to perform a 'SELECT DISTINCT' on an @EllementCollection?

Any help is appreciated!
Richard

Comment: you cannot select a collection like that in your query:https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=963660

Comment: You put me on the right track there. Thank you for your info! I solved it by changing the query to a @NamedNativeQuery directly querying the JPA-generated table.

Comment: Well.. was a bit too soon with my answer. The NamedNativeQuery approach resulted in this bug: http://jdevelopment.nl/hibernates-pure-native-scalar-queries-supported/
So I'm going for an @Embeddable class named Category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused between HQL and SQL .. replace your named query with the following. Named Queries are always HQL.

```
SELECT distinct f.categories FROM FooEntity f
```

But, I'm not sure if this will work. If you need to find out the distinct categories, why query on FooEntity? Why not create an entity for Categories and run a query like below. Also, you are calling join column on a list which is wrong as well ,it should join on entity types like below

```
   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name = "categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id"))
   private List<**Category**> categories; // replace String with Category
```

--

```
select distinct category.name from Category c
```

Where Category is a new entity that you have to create.